# Devise crashes my rails app on heroku, "undefined local variable or method `mimes_for_respond_to'"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

Since adding the devise gem, heroku is unable to load my application in production, giving me the application error:

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

The specific error log from the console is

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:13:in `<class:DeviseController>': undefined local variable or method `mimes_for_respond_to' for DeviseController:Class (NameError)
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /app/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:142:in `require_application_and_environment!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
from /app/bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

I have tried multiple suggestions floating around the internet, but none have worked so far. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rails version? Devise version?

Comment: Rails is '4.2.0.rc3' and Devise is '3.3.0'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fast google search relates your issue with the `responders` gem, that needs to be updated. Please look at [this issue in Devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3160). As long as `responders` is a `Devise` dependency, you don't need to include it in the `Gemfile` (double check that in your `Gemfile.lock`), you just need to update to the last version with:

```
bundle update responders
```

In the case that `responders` gem is not available, then add `gem 'responders'` to your `Gemfile` before running the previous command.

Hope it helps.

Comment: When I try running that command my terminal tells me that it cannot find the gem 'responders'. Responders does not show up in my 'Gemfile.lock' folder either. Devise is there, however.